# Truncate to 2 decimal places without rounding

Tags: dart

Can't find or work out a solution to this that works with Dart.

I've already tried:
1. toStringAsFixed() - this rounds
2. double.parse(number.toStringAsFixed()) - this rounds
3. num - num % 0.01 - this rounds

I've found some solutions on SO but they either use functions that aren't available on Flutter/Dart or didn't work for me.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 14):

To build on @Irn beautiful Answer.

The function below lets you specify how many fractional digits / how many decimal places you want

```
double truncateToDecimalPlaces(num value, int fractionalDigits) => (value * pow(10, 
   fractionalDigits)).truncate() / pow(10, fractionalDigits);
```

Example

```
truncateToDecimalPlace(4321.92385678, 3) // 4321.923
```

Or my favorite way is to use Dart extensions

```
extension TruncateDoubles on double {
   double truncateToDecimalPlaces(int fractionalDigits) => (this * pow(10, 
     fractionalDigits)).truncate() / pow(10, fractionalDigits);
}
```

This lets you call the function on a double object like thus

Usage

```
4321.92385678.truncateToDecimalPlaces(3); // 4321.923
```

Comment: this answer is good, but how can remain the zero, like if 6 decimal place, example result is 0.2 by using your method, how can I add more 5 decimal to become 0.200000

Comment: @FeelRightz I understand your question but I don't think you can return a double as 0.200000 as the computer is expected to just record it as 0.2. Except you want it as a string. if you convert it to a string, you can split it using the decimal place, padRight and join them back .. That should do the trick

Answer (score 3):

Try

```dart
double truncateToHundreths(num value) => (value * 100).truncate() / 100;
```

There will be cases where you lose precision, but that requires you to use almost all 53 bits of double precision in the number (when multiplying by 100 loses precision to begin with).

Going trough strings is a significant overhead that I would avoid if possible, unless you actually expect to convert the number to a string anyway afterwards.

Comment: Thanks :) Really appreciate you taking your time to help me!

Answer (score 1):

`(value * 100).truncateToDouble() / 100`

Example:
`var lat = 29.4562`

lat * 100 = 2945.62
2945.62 `truncateToDouble()` = 2945
2945 / 100 = 29.45

Comment: Code-only answers may solve the problem but they are much more useful if you explain how they solve it. Community requires theory as well as code both to understand your answer fully.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the below method

```
String toFixed(double value, [int decimalPlace = 1]) {
  try {
    String originalNumber = value.toString();
    List<String> formattedNumber = originalNumber.split('.');
    return "${formattedNumber[0]}.${formattedNumber[1].substring(0, decimalPlace)}";
  } catch (_) {}
  return value.toString();
}
```