# Truncate decimal but remain all the 0

Tags: flutter, dart

Flutter has inhouse extension for round-up double to specific decimal string called `toStringAsFixed`. I was finding example for truncate decimal without round-up, and I found this [Truncate to 2 decimal places without rounding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64993877/4401349)

According to this [Truncate to 2 decimal places without rounding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64993877/4401349) , the answer work well.

Example if I want truncate 6 decimal place, `8888.888888888.truncateToDecimalPlaces(6)`, will return `8888.888888` (correct answer I want), but if the number is `8888.800000.truncateToDecimalPlaces(6)` will return `8888.8`, but if I wanted to remain those zero ?

`8888.888888888.truncateToDecimalPlaces(6)` >>> `8888.888888` = `OK`

`8888.800000.truncateToDecimalPlaces(6)` >>> `8888.8` = `NOT OK, wanted to be 8888.800000, remain 6 decimal place`

Comment: You are aware that `truncateToDecimalPlaces` returns `double` and not `String`? Do you want it to return `String` with the number formatted with ending zeroes?

Comment: You can do: `8888.800000.truncateToDecimalPlaces(6).toStringAsFixed(6)` to get the String `8888.800000`.

Comment: if number is `8888.888000` , the `toStringAsFixed` might round up again to `8888.889000`

Comment: `8888.888000.truncateToDecimalPlaces(6).toStringAsFixed(6)` gives `8888.888000`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a problem with `truncateToDecimalPlaces` returning a `String` you can do the following:

```
import 'dart:math';

void main() {
  print(8888.888000.truncateToDecimalPlaces(6)); // 8888.888000
}

extension TruncateDoubles on double {
  String truncateToDecimalPlaces(int fractionalDigits) =>
      ((this * pow(10, fractionalDigits)).truncate() /
              pow(10, fractionalDigits))
          .toStringAsFixed(fractionalDigits);
}
```